# Color a label in CSS

Tags: css, label

Is there a way of changing the Color of this?

```
<label for="Vorname">Vorname: </label>
<input type="text" id="Vorname" >
```

I'm using this as my CSS

```
#vorname {
position: relative;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-size: 150%;
color: white;
```

}
For some Reason its not working D:
Hope someone can help me. Thanks a lot

Comment: `vorname` and `Vorname` are different things.

Comment: Additionally, once you fix that, those CSS rules are going to be applied to the `<input>`, not the `<label>`. If you want to target the `<label>`, give it an ID or class and write CSS for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `#` indicates that the CSS cooresponds to an ID so you should add an id to the label like this:

```
<label id="VornameLable" for="Vorname">Vorname: </label>
<input type="text" id="VornameTextInput" >
```

and the css:

```
#VornameLable {
position: relative;
font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
font-size: 150%;
color: white;
}
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/jr4v102u/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your id is uppercase, while your css is lowercase. If you change #vorname to #Vorname in your css, it should work, however you'll have white text on a white background